# Inproper image for Raspppbery PI Snappy Core?

Tags: server, ubuntu-core, raspberrypi

Why is link meant for Snappy Core for Rasppbery Pi : https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/ pointing to : Ubuntu Classic image for Raspberry Pi 2 (ubuntu-16.04-preinstalled-server-armhf+raspi2.img.xz)
while for Samsung ARTIK it points to ubuntu-15.04-snappy-armhf-rpi2.img

I am asking because the RPI version seems to be just a server version of Ubuntu not a core snappy with no apt-get support. I want the limited version for porpose.
Can someone explain me the difference ?

Answer (score 0):

This should be fixed now: https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/start/raspberry-pi-2/

Ubuntu Core 16 was released last week.